# How to get back data from DB after sent it from client side?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I have profile page in angular js, after I filled and sent them to DB. Then once again if I come back to the same profile page I didn't get any values in the field.

profile.html

```
<form name="profileForm">
            <br/>

                <div flex style="max-width:700px;">
                    <md-input-container class="md-block">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input ng-model="vm.name"></input>
                </md-input-container>
                </div>

                <div flex style="max-width:700px;">
                    <md-input-container class="md-block">
                        <label>Mobile Number</label>
                        <input ng-model="vm.mobile"></input>
                    </md-input-container>
                </div>

                <div flex style="max-width:700px;">
                    <md-input-container class="md-block">
                        <label>Email</label>
                        <input ng-model="vm.email"></input>
                    </md-input-container>
                </div>  

                <div flex style="max-width:700px;">
                <label>DOB:</label>
                    <md-datepicker ng-model="vm.profileForm.dob" md-placeholder="Enter date">
                    </md-datepicker>
                </div>

                <div flex style="max-width:700px;">
                    <md-input-container class="md-block" >
                        <label>Country</label>
                        <md-select ng-model="vm.profileForm.Country" ng-change="vm.getCountryStates()">
                            <md-option ng-repeat="countryName in vm.countries" value="{{countryName.id}}" >
                                {{countryName.country}}
                            </md-option>
                        </md-select>
                    </md-input-container>
                </div>

                <div flex style="max-width:700px;">
                    <md-input-container class="md-block" >
                        <label>State</label>
                        <md-select ng-model="vm.profileForm.State"  ng-change = "vm.getStateCities()">
                            <md-option ng-repeat="stateName in vm.states" value="{{stateName.Id}}">
                                {{stateName.state}}
                            </md-option>
                        </md-select>
                    </md-input-container>
                </div>

                <div flex style="max-width:700px;">
                    <md-input-container class="md-block" >
                        <label>City</label>
                        <md-select ng-model="vm.profileForm.City">
                            <md-option ng-repeat="cityName in vm.cities" value="{{cityName.Id}}">
                                {{cityName.city}}
                            </md-option>
                        </md-select>
                    </md-input-container>
                </div>

                <div flex style="max-width:700px;">
                    <md-input-container class="md-block" >
                        <label>Postal Code</label>
                        <input name="postalCode" ng-model="vm.profileForm.postalCode" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{6}$/" md-maxlength="6">
                    </md-input-container>
                </div>

                <span style="color:green; font-size:20px;">{{vm.message}}</span>

                <div layout="row" layout-align="space-between center">
                    <div>
                        <img src="assets/icons/fonts/backArrow.png" alt="image caption" style="width:18px; height:18px">
                        <a ng-href ng-click="vm.nextTab()" >Back</a>
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin-right:300px">
                        <a ng-href="http://localhost:3000/pages/dashboard">Skip</a>
                        <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="vm.profileInfo(vm.profileForm);">Save & Continue</md-button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

[image: profile page]

In the picture first 3 values getting through ngStorage, after filled remaining fields data stored in DB. For chekcBox I have used cascading dropdown.

profile.js

```
(function ()
 {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.invite-friends')
    .controller('InviteFriendsController', InviteFriendsController);

/** @ngInject */
function InviteFriendsController(Friendslist, $localStorage, $scope, $http, $location, CustomerService)
{
    var vm = this;

    vm.countries = CustomerService.getCountry();

    vm.getCountryStates = function(){
        vm.states = CustomerService.getCountryState(vm.profileForm.Country);    
        vm.cities =[];
    }

    vm.getStateCities = function(){
        vm.cities = CustomerService.getStateCity(vm.profileForm.State);
    }

    vm.uid = $localStorage._id;

    vm.profileInfo = function(userData){
        $http({
            url:'http://192.168.2.8:7200/api/profile_save',
            method:'POST',
            data: {info:userData, loginId:vm.uid}
        }).then(function(res){
            if(res.data.success){
                vm.message = 'Your profile information has been saved successfully.';
                $location.path('/pages/dashboard')
            } 
        }, function(error){
            alert(error.data);
        });
    };

    $http({
        url:'http://192.168.2.8:7200/api/checkIfExists',
        method:'POST',
        data: {userId: vm.uid}
    }).success(function(res){
        vm.name = res.result[0].name;
        vm.mobile = res.result[0].mobile;
        vm.email = res.result[0].email;
        vm.DOB = res.result[0].DOB;
        vm.Country = res.result[0].Country;
        vm.State = res.result[0].State;
        vm.City = res.result[0].City;
        vm.postalCode = res.result[0].PostCode;
    }, function(error){
        alert(error.data);
    });
     }
   })();
```

Comment: Can you post your angular code?

Comment: Is there any code doing data retrieval? If so, could you post it so we can debug? If not, data retrieval must be done so that you can display it.

Comment: yes I have added angular code to my question.

Answer (score 0):

All you ng-model is getting or updating data to vm.profileForm in the view where as while you setting data to view form controller you are adding properties to vm, not to vm.profileForm

Change the following code in $http success 
from

`vm.DOB = res.result[0].DOB;
        vm.Country = res.result[0].Country;
        vm.State = res.result[0].State;
        vm.City = res.result[0].City;
        vm.postalCode = res.result[0].PostCode;`

to

`vm.profileForm.dob = res.result[0].DOB;
        vm.profileForm.Country = res.result[0].Country;
        vm.profileForm.State = res.result[0].State;
        vm.profileForm.City = res.result[0].City;
        vm.profileForm.postalCode = res.result[0].PostCode;`

Comment: ha yes I have added properties to vm only in controller, but where do i put in view because ng-model already has value.

Comment: You have to set vm.profileForm.dob of vm.DOB in contorller. Because you have used vm.profileForm.dob in view. Similar way you have to set  for Country, State, City

Comment: Now i have values in controller from DB, now how do I send values to view ?